# Google MobileAds directory structure for Unity 5 Android game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a mobile game running on Unity 5 using the Google MobileAds plugin. The ads display correctly in my iOS build and receive ads from AdMob, however, I'm unable to build an Android project. This leads me to believe that my implementation of the plugin within my app has been done correctly. I've done extensive research online to try and resolve this. From what I've gathered, I believe either 1) the directory structure of my Unity project is causing the project to be unable to convert classes into dex format or 2) multiple Android manifests and conflicting .jar files are preventing the class conversions into dex format. I have multiple Android manifest files within the directory, including one at the root of the Unity Android folder. As someone with an iOS background, the Android project structure is foreign to me. I'm getting this console output:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
```

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/MyName/Library/Android/sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1;
2 errors; aborting
]

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. See the Console for details.
```

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Users/MyName/Library/Android/sdk/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/BuildTargetTools/AndroidPlayer/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1;
2 errors; aborting
]

Here are images of the directory:
[Top-level directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERaz8.png)
[Root Android folder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay8D8.png)

Should there only be one Android Manifest file in my Unity project? 
Should adding the Google Play Services library eliminate the need to include the Google Analytics plugin?